# How to restart multiple spring boot app instances of a kubernetes service

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a load balanced deployment of spring boot service A, say on a 3 node kubernetes cluster.

I also have a requirement to enable quick configuration management without needing to rebuild+deploy a full blown rebaked image.

For that I put together a spring boot config-server, as well as implemented the Actuator restart on service A which when calling its /restart endpoint on a local single instance deployment it refreshes and loads with the properties fetched from the config-server.

So far so good, but...

How can the above be achieved when service A is deployed on a larger scale k8s deployment with 3, 30 or 300 instances of service A?

Calling /refresh endpoint must be handled by the load balancer as any other REST call on the cluster, meaning it is routed to one of the service instances.

Is there a standard way in springboot-on-k8s I can call each service instance ignoring the LB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't really use the actuator's restart, instead what we do is, utilize the rollingUpdate strategy of deployment.  When we want to "restart" the pods, we issue a kubectl patch.

```
kubectl patch deployment web -p  "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

A good documentation of the upgrade strategy.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81&ved=2ahUKEwjIqtbW_bvfAhUKRY8KHas6DEkQjjgwAnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3HjD4CUoG4ma3HWxquaYjp&cshid=1545776336374

Comment: Even though this is the ideal way, a lot of developers don't have access to fiddle with the kubernetes cluster after deployment. So actuator based approach is quite useful in these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a standard pattern for doing this.

Each of your application pods that match the selector for your service will be registered as an endpoint for that service. If you run `kubectl get endpoints` you should see all the internal clusterIPs for the pods backing your service.

You could create some logic to call that /refresh endpoint for every service endpoint.

Comment: Still, wondering if there's a standardized approach, seems to me as reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The typical way to do this in Kubernetes deployments is to deploy new pods with the updated config rather than reconfigure running pods as Bal Chua mentioned.  Generally pods are supposed to be immutable and re-configuring them in place is an anti-pattern.You wouldn't need to rebuild anything if you externalize your configuration in a configmap or secret.

Comment: I agree that pods are immutable, but since there are no changes in the pod definition, kubernetes is not going to perform an update.  You will have to scale it down to zero, which will lead to downtime.  Treating pods as immutable has always been our go to pattern.  But in cases like this, we just have to bend the rules a little bit.

Comment: I agree with you @BalChua. Using a date label is a nice workaround that I have used in the past as well.