# how to refresh all kubernetes pods with actuator in spring boot config server

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I have a kubernetes cluster which have a config server pod (spring cloud config) and my app running in 3 different pod for HA, exposed by service-ip. 
when i change properties in git and commit+push, i have to call http://service-ip/actuator/refresh.
The problem is that when i call this url, only 1 pod get updated ( the pod that process the current request).

is there any way to solve it ? i see some options to find the pods using kubectl (answer from 2013), but im looking for more native solution.

Answer (score 0):

When a Pod is replaced during a rolling upgrade it will get its config from the config server during startup. So a more k8s-native solution than getting the individual Pod and refreshing the Pod would be to do a no-op rolling upgrade as was suggested in the question [How to recycle pods in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898511/how-to-recycle-pods-in-kubernetes)

If you are changing config as part of a rolling upgrade and the problem relates to timing then you could use a post-start hook on the Pod to do an additional refresh.

Presumably what you are looking at doing otherwise is using a bash script that lists all the Pods and refreshes them, perhaps by doing a 'kubectl exec -it' to shell into the container and call refresh from within it. I can understand your concern that this is not very 'native' as it is quite manual and you would expect a more automatic solution with k8s or with the config server. Actually you sort of have to choose which 'native' approach you want as the config server's refresh-based approach is rather different from the k8s concept of a configmap and a rolling upgrade. (See e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-java-apps-with-kubernetes-configmaps-a ) A solution more native to the config server is to do messaging to alert the services that new config is available - see the links at the end of https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-config-server-for-the-impatient

Comment: An option that fits in between is the config options in the spring cloud kubernetes project (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes). But if you are already using the config server then I imagine you probably aren't looking to switch to that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually im not about upgrade, just changing config in configuration-repo and 'telling' to pod to refresh itself.

Comment: So the problem is how best to 'tell' the Pods to all refresh themselves as presumably you aren't looking to do something as complex as https://springbootdev.com/2018/07/21/spring-cloud-config-using-git-webhook-to-auto-refresh-the-config-changes-with-spring-cloud-stream-spring-cloud-bus-and-rabbitmq-part-3/ ?

Comment: One way to 'tell' all the Pods to refresh would be to initiate a rolling upgrade. Then they would progressively be killed and replaced with new Pods and the new Pods would have the new config. There is a way to do a rolling upgrade even if you don't have code changes in the underlying app.

Comment: @chenchuk see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842209/how-to-restart-multiple-spring-boot-app-instances-of-a-kubernetes-service